# rJava loading and executing in shell but not in cron

Tags: r, linux, cron, centos, rjava

I am facing a unusual problem on CENTOS 7 system with R 3.6.x. This involves working with rJava Package.

Steps i'm taking to run in root,

```
sudo -i changing to root
Rscript /opt/mount1/code.R
```

When triggered from bash from /opt/mount1/code.R the code works fine both in personal account and root access.

when the same script is triggered through root's cron scheduler, the Rscript is executed, but unable to load  `rjava`

I have checked the /opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so' existing in this location and works without issue when triggered in terminal.

I also ran a test script in cron to see the R.home file.path(R.home("bin"), "R") this also outputs "/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/bin/R"

Please excuse my terminology if its not right.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

This is the error

```
> Loading required package: DBI Loading required package: rJava Error:
> package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:  .onLoad failed in
> loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath =
> DLLpath, ...)   error: unable to load shared object
> '/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':   libjvm.so: cannot
> open shared object file: No such file or directory Error: package
> ‘rJava’ could not be loaded 
> Execution halted
```

Comment: a) You can run `cron` jobs as you too.  There is a user field.  b)  The difference you see will be due to different environment variables such as `$PATH`  and/or Java settings. You will have to track that down.  You did demonstrate to yourself that it _can_ run on the machine, now you need to normalize the setup between both accounts. Or, per a), run as you.

Comment: Thank you @dirk I tried running this on my account's crontab but ended up with the same java error.  Seems like something is changing on Cron side and want to figure how how to diagonise it.

Comment: same issue. rjava is not loading when executing script from cron 

Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for â€˜rJavaâ€™:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/opt/R/3.6.3/lib/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package â€˜rJavaâ€™ could not be loaded
Execution halted

from bash executes the code
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava